# .htcaccess redirecionamento 301 não funciona

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

O redirecionamento de `https://www.meusite.com` para `https://meusite.com` não funciona.
E como resultado fico com o site em duplicado, numa página estou logado e na outra não.

```xml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não está funcionando porque você está comentando as linhas que "fazem o trabalho" (linhas 3 a 5). Tente, então, remover os símbolos `#` do começo dessas linhas:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```